# How to run specific script by specific schedule in Azure devOps?

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml, cypress, schedule

I have **two schedules**, **first one** runs my tests every **10 minutes** and **the second one** runs my tests **at 1 AM**. I want the **first schedule** to run only the `npm run cy:healthCheck` script and the second schedule `npm run cy:test` script. How can I reach that behaviour.

Here is the YAML file for only running my `npm run cy:healthCheck` script every 10 minutes - [Pastebin link of YAML](https://pastebin.pl/view/37b87c11)

Answer (score 1):

I see two options

1. Create template from an existing pipeline, and then have 2 pipelines using template with different schedule and parameter that will be condition to run one or second task.
2. Have two schedule in one pipeline like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) adding task for calculating variable for condition

```
schedules:
- cron: "0 0 * * *"
  displayName: Daily midnight build
- cron: "0 12 * * 0"
  displayName: Weekly Sunday build

- powershell: |
        $a=get-date
        if($a.Hour -eq 11 -and ($a.Minute -lt 5 -or $a.Minute -gt 55))
        {
            $TimeToRunSecondTask=(1 -eq 1)
        }       
          Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=FileExists]$TimeToRunSecondTask"   
- task: 
  condition: eq(variables['TimeToRunSecondTask'], True)
```

Comment: Having 2 yaml files solves my problem. Do you think it is a good way to solve my problem?

Comment: I would create template that would call from this 2 pipelines to do not repeat code.